issue in creation of django project
(venv2) PS C:\dev\trydjango> django-admin startproject myproject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\dev\trydjango\venv2\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Dev\trydjango\venv2\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "C:\Dev\trydjango\venv2\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\version.py", line 5, in <module>
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

I tried everything from reinstalling the python to repairing it but this issue doesn't get solve
please suggest any other method to resolve this issue

What is the version of Django?
